# Outdoor low-voltage 12 V landscape lighting systems: transformer vs SMPS

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, lighting, outdoors

Why are 12 V transformers so popular for outdoor low-voltage landscape lighting systems vs using a 12 V switch-mode power supply?

From my understanding, a switch-mode power supply is smaller, more efficient, and cheaper than a transformer (as well as quieter as there is no transformer AC hum). Is there a safety or reliability issue, or something else?

As an example, you can search Amazon for `12v outdoor lighting power supply` to see the variants.

Comment: Transformers produce AC, while SMPS produce DC. Both products are sold because some lights require one or the other. Eventually I expect DC to become a lot more popular because it's more logical for LED lighting.

Answer (score 1):

Transformers are much more durable, particularly against ESD which will be an issue for outdoor lighting.

Answer (score 0):

Using AC voltage will reduce corrosion which is good for outdoor stuff that gets wet.